# Persistent data on filesystem in service fabric

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, azure-service-fabric

I am wrapping elastic search on windows in a service fabric stateless service, such it runs the elastic search node on each node that the service is running.

Elastic Search is distributed in the code package and can be updated with the application.

So in a 3 node service fabric, the elastic node will get the name of each node in service fabric.

What would be the best approach to locate the data for elastic node?

My own idea would be to locate it on the VM temp disks, as long as more nodes are up, then elastic should replicate data internal such one node can die.

Then i would also do daily backups copying all data to external storage to be able to restore it.

Is there any other options that I should consider?